# Zed Attack Proxy only crawling one page

Tags: owasp, scanning, zap

I have just recently started using Zed Attack Proxy(ZED) to check for OWASP vulnerabilities and I am trying to get it to scan my whole site. I have successfully got it to login as a user and scan from there but it stays on the main page after logging in. Is there a way to get it to scan the other pages throughout the website? Also, is there a way to test for specific vulnerabilities only or is it more of a broad scan of everything? I am still new to this software so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a one sentence answer, and will probably need quite a bit more info from you. I'd recommend asking them on the [ZAP User Group](https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users) that way we can walk you through things a bit more easily.

Cheers, Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have posted  my issue on the Zap user group

Comment: Direct link to the thread for reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/5sFdAn2M4xk/9HW6gAcLBwAJ